# Java get query expansion terms

Tags: java

Does anyone know if its possible to easily get query expansion terms programmatically using Java?

For example when you do a google search, at the bottom of the results page there is a "Searches Related to [term]" section, is there a way to harvest those terms? I feel like this would be easiest.

I dont want to create my own query expansion algorithm because of time constraints and would like a quick and easy way to get the terms.

for example "fashion design" -> ["fashion design courses", "fashion design careers", "fashion design sketches"]

thank you in advance for any help

-MC

Comment: Do you really intend to search the web or is your intent simply to parse the natural language into an easy to traverse Java Object?

Answer (score 0):

You could scrape the google answer to your query (making an `HTTP request`), capture the content near `"Search relates.."` section, and extract suggested terms.

**Pro:**

- You use google (without implementing your query-expansion algorithm).

**Cons:**

- You need internet connection

Comment: thanks, that sounds exactly like something I would want to try. Would you mind explaining how I can capture the content of the page? when I try to get content from a url like: "http://www.google.com/search?q=example" I get a 403 response code (probably because google doesnt want me using it like this...)

Comment: Do you really intend to search the web or is your intent simply to parse the natural language into an easy to traverse Java Object?

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia page for [query expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_expansion) points to two Java implementations that might be helpful:

- [LucQE](http://lucene-qe.sourceforge.net/)
- [LuceneQE](http://grasia.fdi.ucm.es/jose/query-expansion/)

Answer (score 0):

```
QueryParser.parse(string) ;
```

This simple yet powerful call uses [Lucene's Query Parser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) to parse the string and returns a Query object that contains all the Terms in a tree like structure. Use this to convert a natural language search query like *content:(whatever)  in:(inbox,sent) AND body:(something) NOT (nothing)* into an appropriate tree structure retaining all the logical conditions such as AND OR NOT etc and it is really easy to traverse. Now your java app has the power of understanding simple google like syntax. Of course you also need a powerful back end to support such searches! Lucene can help you with that as well.